# How to launch the graph as initial activity using achartengine

Tags: java, android, graph, achartengine

In my app i want to display the graph when app launches. For this i used the tab activity. is it possible to implement this without tab activity? if yes, then how to implement this. please can anybody help me.

**code:**

```
public class ALinegraph extends TabActivity {

    TabHost tab_host;
    TabSpec tab1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

        tab_host = getTabHost();   
        tab1 = tab_host.newTabSpec("1wk"); 
        tab1.setIndicator("1wk");

        Linegraphpage ACTC = new Linegraphpage();
        Intent intent = ACTC.execute(ALinegraph.this);      
        tab1.setContent(intent);     
        tab_host.addTab(tab1);     
    }

}
```

Comment: checkout complete example of achartEngine

Comment: I am also face same type of problem but not getting a perfect solution.

Comment: If Linegraphpage extends Activity you could just launch it directly by adding it as a Activity to the manifest. If it's some view of some kind just put it as setContentView(new Linegraphpage());, addView or add it to a xml layout.